# Dilemma: Structure of Similar Websites

Tags: seo, branding, permalinks, ux, user-experience

I have created music and movies knowledge sites for use locally in my country (think of Genius and IMDb). Both were built differently (by different people) and do not share anything.

But I am in a dilemma on how to structure the links in a way that wouldn't have a negative impact on branding and SEO. My choices are (examples):

### Structure 1: Subdirectories

**Music:** `msite.co/music/`
**Movies:** `msite.co/movies/`
Stronger domain authority? They'd each have their own homepage, then I'd grab contents from both sites to display on the frontpage. Frontpage clutter?

### Structure 2: Subdomains

**Music:** `music.msite.co`
**Movies:** `movies.msite.co`
Same as 1?

### Structure 3: Separate sites, Same name

**Music:** `msite.co`
**Movies:** `msite.tv`
The M in the name can stand for either music or movies (or just media).

### Structure 4: Separate sites, Different names

**Music:** `Msite.co`
**Movies:** `Fsite.co`
M for music and F for films.

PS: I had chosen the current name because the M might stand for both music and movies (or I could just call it Media).

Things that worry me are: User experience, Niche sites, SEO, Link juice, Branding, Concentrated promotional efforts.

Advice?

Comment: Is there a reason why it cannot be just one site?? Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @closetnoc. They use two different softwares. Both of which were not built by me.

Comment: I just took a closer look at your question (still drinking my morning coffee so I am a bit slow). Your structure 1 looks like a single site. I assume you know how to make this happen to fit your software requirements. If that is the case, my personal opinion, is that is your best option since you will be building value for one domain name and not several. This is always preferred when appropriate since it is more powerful. Consider that music and movies target the same audience/interest and compliment each other semantically. Cheers!!

Comment: Very insightful @closetnoc. I did not know that music and movies target the same audience. Structure 1 is my current status but lately I felt separating them might make sense not to confuse users. Thank you. I would love to know what other people think.

Comment: Surveying others for their opinion  is off topic at this website